# Atrribute Error:'module"object has no attribute python 3.2

Tags: python

I have two python files:

`test.py`

```
def k():
    print ("I am a test")
    print ("see! I do nothing productive.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    k()
```

`test2.py`

```
import test
print ("a")
test.k()
```

but when I run test2.py it show the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    test.k()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'k'
```

Comment: There's a [built-in `test` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/test.html), so it's generally a good idea to avoid using that name for your own modules. You're probably importing the built-in module.

Comment: @user2357112, it's work, last time I tried : using subprocess.call("python test.py"),why it doesn't worK? and this method as well, import os, os.system("python test.py"),it doesn't work also?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do - import a module, or start a new process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you're shadowing a built-in module called "test". If you rename "test.py" to any other name (that is isn't a built-in module), import it, and have both files residing in the same folder, it will run properly.

For example:

**temp_test.py**

```
def k():
    print("Test!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    k()
```

**temp_test2.py**

```
import temp_test

print("a")
temp_test.k()
```

Running temp_test2.py produces this output:

> a
>   Test!

In regards to your comment, your attempt at using `subprocess.call()` failed because you need to either add the `shell=True` argument so a shell can parse and interpret the command, or you need to split your arguments into a list and pass that instead:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('python temp_test.py', shell=True)
```

Or:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', 'temp_test.py'])
```

I don't know why your `os.system()` call failed. This works for me on 2.7:

```
import os
os.system('python temp_test.py')
```

### TL;DR

1. Your module/file name is the same as a built-in module. Name it something else.
2. Read the [subprocess.call() docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call). You're launching subprocesses incorrectly.

Last note: The content of your question deals with different subject matter than your attempted workarounds listed in your comments (module importing vs. subprocess launching). These are two very different things so make sure you do some reading up on them before you continue work on whatever script you're writing so you can use the right one for your task.

Comment: hi, when I tried to run the os.system and subporcess, it pop out the cmd window in few second and then close it, so how can I halt the cmd window?

Comment: Request input from the user at the end the script that is being launched in the extra window using `input()` for Python3 or `raw_input()` for Python2.